# Apache Spark: RDD multiple passes with a simple operation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, rdd, set-intersection

I've encountered this problem, as I'm learning Apache Spark framework.
Consider the following simple RDD

```
scala> val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List((1, Set("C3", "C2")), 
                                      (2, Set("C1", "C5", "C3")), 
                                      (3, Set("C2", "C7"))))
rdd1: RDD[(Int, Set[String])]
```

I want to intersect each Set in every element in `rdd1` with the sets of every other element in the "same" `rdd1`; so that the results would be of the form:

```
newRDD: RDD[(Int, Int, Set[String])]
// and newRDD.collect will look like:
newRDD: Array[(Int, Int, Set[String])] = Array((1, 1, Set("C3", "C2")), (1, 2, Set("C3")), (1, 3, Set("C2")),
                                               (2, 1, Set("C3")), (2, 2, Set("C1", "C5", "C3")), (2, 3, Set()),
                                               (3, 1, Set("C2")), (3, 2, Set()), (1, 3, Set("C2", "C7")))
```

I tried nesting `rdd1` like so

```
scala> val newRDD = rdd1 map (x => {rdd1 map (y => (x._1, y._1, x._2.intersect(y._2)))})
```

however, this will throw 'Task not serilizable' exception. 
Now if I wanted to avoid `rdd1.collect()` or any other action operations before performing

```
scala> val newRDD = rdd1 map (x => {rdd1 map (y => (x._1, y._1, x._2.intersect(y._2)))})
```

would it be possible to achive the desired `newRDD`?

Comment: *Note: rdd1 is reduced to 3 elements for illustration purposes; the rdd1 that I'm working with has over 300K elements of the same form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you are getting 'Task not serilizable' exception is because you are trying to put an `RDD` in a map for an other `RDD`, in this case Spark would try to serialise the second `RDD`. Normally this kind of problem you'd solve with joins:

```
val newRDD = rdd1.cartesian(rdd1).map { case ((a, aSet), (b, bSet)) =>
   (a, b, aSet.intersect(bSet))
}
```

Here the cartesian join creates a pair of each sets in a new `RDD`, which you can intersect.

Comment: though the cartesian() method would increase rdd1 size by a power of 2; it seems like it is the only possible solution that dose not involve action operation.

Comment: they both O(n^2), in terms of complexity.